# Additional references in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

I have a master `BibTeX` file that gets updated and maintained by `BibDesk`. I link to it from my TeX documents, but would sometimes like to add "on the fly" references without having to add these to `BibDesk` in order for them to get put into the master file. In other words, I would like the option to "mix in" additional `\bibitems` into my bibliography, something like:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Papers/master.bib}
\bibitem{additional}Authors, paper, etc.
```

(Of course, this gives errors.) Any suggestions? Many thanks, and my apologies if this is a very standard or silly question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two solutions possible:

## 1. Patch the `\end{thebibliography}` as follows:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
% all your extra bibitems go here
\bibitem{extra1}A. Uthor, Some Extra Paper, vol 123, p.2--3 
}
```

Do not forget to put `\usepackage{etoolbox}` somewhere in the preamble. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
% all your extra bibitems go here
\bibitem{extra1}A. Uthor, Some Extra Paper, vol 123, p.2--3 
}

Cite from above \cite{extra1}.
Cite from bib-file \cite{bookWhatever}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Papers/master.bib} 

\end{document}
```

## 2. Create a "local" bib file.

Basically, the same trick, as has been suggested already by R. Schumacher.
But, if you prefer to keep everything in one .tex file, just do like in the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mylocalbib.bib}
@article{extra1,
  title={Title},
  author={A. Uthor},
  journal={PRL},
  volume={12},
  pages={123--124},
  year={1999},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{extra1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Papers/master.bib,mylocalbib} 
% here both your "global" and "local" bib-files are mentioned

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `\usepackage{filecontents}` to your preamble to make alternative (2) work, see [filecontents documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf)

Comment: @ vaettchen: no, actually, you don't

Comment: Your second solution worked nicely, but it's your first one I would really prefer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here's what my code looks like at the end of the document:
     \bibliographystyle{plain}
     \bibliography{/Users/Papers/master.bib}
     \AtEndEnvironment{thebibliography}{
     \bibitem{extra1}
     A. Uthor, Some Extra Paper, vol 123, p.2--3
With etoolbox loaded. Any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: I added a MWE to my first solution. Just try copy-pasting it and compiling with `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`. Note that `bibtex` will complaint 'Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "extra1"'

Comment: In addition to the answer by amorua, I notice that the \AtEndEnvironment macro doesn't seem to exist in default texlive package for ubuntu. I had to patch the etoolbox package by downloading and doing the 'manual install' from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox

Comment: Solution (1) is great!  However, regardless of the names of things, it seems to put the extra references at the end of my bibliography.  Is there any way to make it thread them in alphabetically?

Comment: The solution 1 indeed worked for me too but as noted by @AaronMazel-Gee it puts the bibitem list at the end of the bibliography generated by bibtex without integrating alphabetically.  Somehow expected but useful only as a 'quick patch'. At the end, I guess that the only proper solution is to create another bib file.

Answer (score 1):

I teach my students to use [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/).  And in this case simply have a second ***.bib** file with the local additions.  Assume you call it **mybib.bib**, keep it in the same folder as the main document, then you would use
`\bibliography{/Users/Papers/master.bib,mybib.bib}`. JabRef runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  The advantage of this is that you can either keep separate **mybib.bib** in each folder or use a common one located in your */Users/Papers/* folder.

The only important caution is that if you have duplicate keywords in the different ***.bib** file it will use the first one it finds in the order in the \bibliography command.